# Function type inferences in match

Tags: f#

Please, could someone explain why here the function type is inferred to be string -> string?

```
let myFunc a:string = 
    match a with 
    | "A" -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

This works fine when the argument is generic, but as soon as I add :string the type changes. Why?

**Edit:**
I want to declare the argument type to be a string as I actually want to use String.ToUpper() for the match:

```
let myFunc a:string = 
    match a.ToUpper() with 
    | "A" -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

A bit awkward solution would, be this

```
let myFunc a = 
    match a.ToString().ToUpper() with 
    | "A" -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

But I really know it will be a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By writing `:string` at the end of the function signature, you're declaring the return type  to be `string`. The type of `a` is inferred to be `string` because you pattern match it against strings, so the type of the function becomes `string -> string`.

Presumably you meant for the `:string` to apply to `a`, not the result of the function. To achieve this you'd need to surround it with parentheses like this:

```
let myFunc (a : string) =
```

Or if you want to specify both the argument type and the return type:

```
let myFunc (a : string) : bool =
```

Comment: Darn! I should better learn the syntax first. :) Thanks, sepp2k!